# How to check a array includes or not in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, include

I have a 2d array like,

```
arr = [
[1,"kader"],
[3,"nader"],
[2,"sader"],
[7,"abul"]
]
```

now I want to check is [3,"nader"] is present or not in my 2d list or not,

if I use
`includes()` function, it's not working
like,

```
arr = [
[1,"kader"],
[3,"nader"],
[2,"sader"],
[7,"abul"]
]

if (arr.includes([3,"nader"])){
console.log(true)
}else{
console.log(false)
}
```

it shout print `true` but gives me `false`

what should I do?

Comment: It's because `[3,"nader"] === [3,"nader"] // false`. Consider using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Two different arrays are never `===` to each other, which is the test that `includes` uses. Classicly, `[] === []` is `false`.

Instead, use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if any element in the array matches your condition (a condition that, in this case, might involve using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as well):

```
const target = [3, "nader"];
console.log(
    arr.some(
        (e) => e.length === target.length &&
               e.every((value, index) => value === target[index])
    )
);
```

```js
const arr = [
    [1, "kader"],
    [3, "nader"],
    [2, "sader"],
    [7, "abul"],
];

const target = [3, "nader"];
console.log(
    arr.some(
        (e) => e.length === target.length && e.every((value, index) => value === target[index])
    )
);
```

In that example I'm being quite strict, requiring that the arrays be exact matches for each other, but you can adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
arr.some(x => look4.every(y => x.includes(y)) && x.every(y => look4.includes(y)))
```

as in the demo below:

```js
const 
      arr = [[1,"kader"],[3,"nader"],[2,"sader"],[7,"abul"]],
      
      look4 = [3,"nader"];

if ( arr.some(x => look4.every(y => x.includes(y)) && x.every(y => look4.includes(y))) ) {
    console.log(true)
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With JavaScript, you can use the includes() function in combination with the JSON.stringify() method to see if [3, "nader"] is present in your 2D array. Here's a sample code piece that shows how to do it:

```
let arr = [
  [1, "kader"],
  [3, "nader"],
  [2, "sader"],
  [7, "abul"],
];

let searchItem = [3, "nader"];

let found = arr.some(
  (item) => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(searchItem)
);

if (found) {
  console.log(`Item '${JSON.stringify(searchItem)}' found in array`);
} else {
  console.log(`Item '${JSON.stringify(searchItem)}' not found in array`);
}
```

hope it helps